# turning wso2 into a pep with identity server acting as the pdp

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am trying to use wso2 ESB server as a PEP, I already have wso2 identity server acting as the PDP and an application hosted on wso2 Application server.  I have uploaded policies into identity server and I was wondering if there any tutorials out there that both show and explain how to make this happen. I have tried the blog http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/08/finegrained-authorization-restful-services-xacml but it has not worked.  any direction on how to turn esb into a pep would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can use wso2 esb Entitlement mediator. Have a look at following guide which explains how we can add fine grained authorization to proxy services.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/IS400/Adding+Fine-grained+Authorization+for+Proxy+Services+in+ESB